# Getting timeout from server when connecting through virtual machine

Tags: iis, virtual-machines, timeout

I have an angular application running on a IIS server, on the same server i have an asp core backend application.
When i'm connecting from my computer i have no issue.
Weh i'm connecting to my virtual machine in china, i can open my angular application front fine.
But all request to the server are getting 504 timeout ...
i thought about port issue , but if it was that i wouldn't be able to reach my front , the port of the front and back are 4433 and 4430 these are custom port.

Anyone would have an idea for me ? I'll take it gladly

Comment: Please always host your web apps on standard ports (80 and/or 443).

Comment: i cant because those are not open on the server =( and i have two application on the same server so they can't both use the same port anyway

Comment: "They can't both use the same port anyway"? I wonder from where you learned that invalid fact. IIS does allow multiple sites to use the same port for decades, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Comment: Ok thanks for the example so from your documentation if i bind two website on port 443, one address would be myip:443:myfirstwebsite and the other one myip:443:mysecondwebsite ? is that correct ?

Comment: Yes. But if your choice is port 443, you also need to learn certificate mappings in Windows HTTP API, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html or the certificates cannot be properly selected.

Comment: Thanks for the resources mate, also why is it mandatory for you to host on standart ports ?